# Sound card not being detected by programs

Tags: audio, sound-card, toshiba-laptop

While I was watching a YouTube video on my Toshiba Satellite p55-A5312 the sound repeated itself several times and my sound stopped working. I signed out and restarted several times yet it still did not work.

The computer detects the sound-card yet it cannot produce system/program sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [the latest audio driver](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4003789) for your computer. See if installing that solves it.